# Filter the Datatable rows

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, datatable

I am trying to filter the rows of datable. When the user checks the checkboxes in each row and hits Filter Screen, it should just retain the checked rows and remove/hide the un checked ones from the screen. 
When I hit filter screen, either all rows shows up or nothing shows up. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code

[image]
controller Code

```
global class SCF_ReportPage_Ctrl {

    //List<Supply_Chain_Framework__c> countryList= new List<Supply_Chain_Framework__c>();
  public Static List<String> ToBeShownList = new List<String>();
  public boolean flag= false;
  public SCF_ReportPage_Ctrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  }
  public List<Supply_Chain_Framework__c> countryList{
    get{
      if(flag==false){
        System.debug('listr'+ToBeHiddenList);
        countryList= [select id,Direct_Model__c,name,filter__c, Triad_Model__c, Flow_Thru_Model__c, Employment_Law__c, IC_SOW_Framework__c, Supplier_Network_Maturity__c,Risk__c, Corruption__c from Supply_Chain_Framework__c  limit 100];
      }

      return countryList;
    }
    set;
  }

  public PageReference updatePage() {
    system.debug('---in update page');
    flag = true;
    countryList = [select id,Direct_Model__c,name,filter__c, Triad_Model__c, Flow_Thru_Model__c, Employment_Law__c, IC_SOW_Framework__c, Supplier_Network_Maturity__c,Risk__c, Corruption__c from Supply_Chain_Framework__c where id in :ToBeShownList ];
    ToBeShownList.clear();
    return null;
  }

  @RemoteAction
  global static string saveNodeAttachments(string selections) {
    system.debug('.....'+selections);
    List<string> A = selections.split(';');
    ToBeShownList.addAll(A);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old to deprecate.

Answer (score 0):

You must rerender the pageblock to show the updated data.

Add an id to your pageblock

```
<apex:PageBlock id="pageBlock">
```

....
....

....

And then add the rerender attribute to your commandbutton like this:

```
<apex:commandbutton ........... reRender="pageBlock">
```